# What are the "hidden sectors" in the output of the `file` command for partitions containing FAT32?

Tags: linux, partitioning, filesystems, fat32

I have divided an external USB hard drive in two partitions using GParted. Both are primary partitions formatted as FAT32 and have the same size (500 GB). This is the output of `file -s`:

```
/dev/sdb1: DOS/MBR boot sector, code offset 0x58+2, OEM-ID "mkfs.fat", sectors/cluster 64, reserved sectors 64, Media descriptor 0xf8, sectors/track 63, heads 255, hidden sectors 2048, sectors 976760832 (volumes > 32 MB), FAT (32 bit), sectors/FAT 119232, reserved 0x3, serial number 0x99034dfb, label: "TOSHIBA1   "

/dev/sdb2: DOS/MBR boot sector, code offset 0x58+2, OEM-ID "mkfs.fat", sectors/cluster 64, reserved sectors 64, Media descriptor 0xf8, sectors/track 63, heads 255, hidden sectors 976762880, sectors 976760832 (volumes > 32 MB), FAT (32 bit), sectors/FAT 119232, reserved 0x1, serial number 0x96cbe274, label: "TOSHIBA2   "
```

In `/dev/sdb2`, what is `hidden sectors` and why is it bigger than `sectors`?
The difference is 2048, which happens to be the value of `hidden sectors` for `/dev/sdb1`. Is this a coincidence? An error of GParted or of the `file` command? More importantly, is it something to be concerned about?

Comment: I suggest redoing it with another tool than GParted.

Comment: FAT32 is not really recommended for large partitions. It has no journal for recovery from errors and cannot store a file over 4GB. If using with Windows NTFS is better or with Linux then ext4 is better. Both have journals and can store larger files.

Comment: @oldfred I know. I am using FAT32 for compatibility between different systems, as I need to use the drive on both Windows and Linux (and occasionally MacOS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tl;dr

Nothing to worry about.

---

Wikipedia article [*Design of the FAT file system*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_of_the_FAT_file_system) mentions "hidden sectors" few times and the common description of the relevant metadata entries is

> Count of hidden sectors preceding the partition that contains this FAT volume. This field should always be zero on media that are not partitioned.

(with few quirks). This description seems to fit the values you observe in your particular case.

---

I expect Linux tools to never use this value by default. In your case the respective values `2048` and `976762880` are valid in the context of `/dev/sdb`, but if you consider `/dev/sdb1` and `/dev/sdb2` respectively then these devices are not partitioned, so in their context "hidden sectors" should be `0`.

It's common to mount with like `mount /dev/sdb1 /some/mountpoint`, but if the partition starts at the offset of 2048 sectors of 512 bytes then you can do the same with

```
mount -o offset=$((2048*512)) /dev/sdb /some/mountpoint
```

So there is no clear indication which context is the "right" one as far as Linux is concerned. Another hint that "hidden sectors" value shouldn't matter is the fact that it embeds information that belongs to the partition table into metadata structures of the filesystem. Nowadays we tend not to mix abstraction layers like this. It's relatively easy to "desynchronize" the two pieces of information. And since the OS needs to read the partition table to find the filesystem in the first place, redundant information about the offset available only after you already know the offset is hardly useful.

Note there is another redundant information: partition tables contain [partition IDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_type) (MBR) or [partition type GUIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_type_GUIDs) (GPT) which should correspond to the actual filesystems in the partitions, but may not. However this information, if coherent, is quite useful because you can learn what to expect (what OS, possible multiboot, swap partitions) by examining just the partition table. In practice sometimes this is useful for humans and sometimes for machines; especially UEFI needs to know which partition is [EFI system partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_system_partition). But if you tell Linux to `mount /dev/sdb1 …` it will try to detect the actual filesystem there rather than to examine `/dev/sdb`, read the partition table and use the partition ID/GUID.

I don't know what was the rationale behind "hidden sectors". Nevertheless it seems there were/are some devices that rely on this value somehow. Compare [`man 8 mkfs.fat`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mkfs.vfat):

> `-h number-of-hidden-sectors`
>   Select the number of hidden sectors in the volume. Apparently some digital cameras get indigestion if you feed them a CF card without such hidden sectors, this option allows you to satisfy them. Assumes `0` if no value is given on the command line.

It appears GParted went ahead and tried to satisfy even "some digital cameras" or whatever. So this is a *good thing*. You absolutely don't need to redo with another tool.

Comment: Thank you, that's a very thorough explanation. I assume one can use a `fsck` to check the consistency and integrity of filesystem and partition table?

Comment: @rs028 `fsck` doesn't verify partition tables. Although if it finds no errors in the filesystem it means the partition is at the right offset and big enough. If the existence of "hidden sectors" is your only concern then there is no reason to believe *anything* is wrong. Unless there were errors in GParted; but I guess if there had been errors, then you would have told us in the question body in the first place.

Comment: No I don't have reason to believe anything is wrong. The question was just to understand better how it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

‘Hidden sectors’ is a misnomer for the partition offset, as stored in the FAT or NTFS boot sector, in a data structure (also misleadingly) called the [BIOS Parameter Block](https://jdebp.uk/FGA/bios-parameter-block.html); here, ‘BIOS’ refers to a component of MS-DOS and not to system firmware.  The value is (supposed to be) the number of sectors that precede the boot sector on disk.  Nothing more, nothing less.  For a FAT file system that resides on non-partitioned media and spans the whole disk, it should be zero.

When the FAT or NTFS boot sector is loaded, it uses the ‘hidden sectors’ value to locate the partition on the disk.  From there the boot sector is able to locate file system structures and load a later-stage bootloader, such as IO.SYS (MSLOAD), NTLDR or BOOTMGR.  Other than that, the value is generally not used.  So if you don’t plan to boot from that file system on a BIOS system, it shouldn’t even matter at all… though you never know what crazy FAT implementations you will run into.